# JAX-RS JSON Formatting

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using JAX-RS for RESTful web services. In doing so I am serializing an object to JSON. My problem is the JSON I get back contains a `name` attribute that does not exist on my original object. I would like to get rid of it. Example:

```
public class TestClass {
   private string var1;
   private int var2;

   "getters and setters"
}
```

The JSON I get returned, once I instantiate, is:

```
{
   "var1": "Hello World".
   "var2": 7
   "name": "TestClass"
}
```

How do I get rid of that `name` attribute?

Comment: Are you using jackson, and which jax-rs framework in general? Also, it might potentially be from a getter, if you have something like `getName()`.

Comment: I am using javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar. I only have two getters and two setters. One for each of the variables.